# Why do i get strange output from RFID reader with python?

Tags: python, string, parsing, serial-port, codec

I'm using this script:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0') 
print 'Running..'
while True:
    a=ser.read()      # write a string
    if a is not "":
        print str(a)
        break

ser.close()
```

..and when im running the script i'm getting this output:

```
/Documents/python$ python rfid.py
```

As you can see i'm getting this strange box instead of the ID-string, so i'm guessing it has to do with some codec? EDIT: actually you cant see it here, but the box i'm talking about contains three zeroes and a two, like this:

```
0 0
0 2
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `is` or `is not` to test for equality, only for identity, most usually with `None`. The Pythonic (recommended) way here would be `if a:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing that because U+0002 is not a printable character. You're receiving 0x02 as (part of?) the message from the device; you can use `od` to see the whole message as output by the script. If you didn't expect that then you may want to make sure that you've used `setserial` to set the appropriate properties for the serial line.

Comment: i'm a beginner with python and serial communication.. how do you use setserial? i'm on a Ubuntu Linux machine, if that has anything to say.